# how to vertically scroll to an element in robot framework, with selenium2library

Tags: robotframework

please let me know how to vertically scroll to a particular element in robot framework with selenium2library.
     I have dynamically changing values , that i am appending in the xpath and want to scroll to that element.

below is the syntax that i have  tried.

```
Execute Javascript  window.document.getElementByXpath('//div[@data-documenttype= "${name}"]).scrollIntoView(true);
```

Comment: Could you provide your full test case

Comment: Have you had a look at [robotframework-extendedselenium2library](https://github.com/rickypc/robotframework-extendedselenium2library)?

Comment: @A.Kootstra, yes i did upgrade library, but later my test cases with "class" locator were not running, so again i had to go back to selenium2library

Comment: @WojtekT  Complete test case is to scroll to all the mandatory fields and upload files, it is working , but as list grows i have to scroll down, at this point am facing issue

Answer (score 0):

```
***Settings***
Library  ExtendedSelenium2Library

*** Keywords ****
**Scroll Right Panel To Click a File**
Scroll Element Into View    ${Element-path-From}
Wait Until Element is visible    ${Element-Path-To}     timeout=5s
Set Focus To Element    ${Element-Path-To}
Click Element    ${Element-Path-To}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have to setup the extra library. This works for me:
Execute JavaScript    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)

Comment: This only works if you wanted to scroll to the end of the page.
The question is about scrolling to a specific element in the page. Not necessarily at the end of the page.